# How to use automatic memory management with IMFMediaBuffer in Win32 C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following code snippet

```
IMFMediaBuffer* pBuffer;
pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer);
DWORD length;
pBuffer->GetCurrentLength(&length);
unsigned char* data;
HRESULT hr = pBuffer->Lock(&data, NULL, &length);
```

The ConvertToContiguousBuffer() function gives me a contiguous buffer as an IMFMediaBuffer object. Then the Lock() method sets the data pointer to point to the data. The problem is I need to share the data between multiple threads. I'd like to use automatic memory management (shared_ptr) but the problem is the pointer is initialised in the Lock function. How to use shared_ptr in that case. How to initialize a shared_ptr with the dangling pointer (data). I thought of using CComPtr on the IMFMediaBuffer and to use std::move() to move the data around. The problem is I need to send the data over on the network. I need the data to be in the unsigned char format. I need something like:

```
unsigned char* data;
HRESULT hr = pBuffer->Lock(&data, NULL, &length);
std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> datapointer (data);
```

The problem is I'm getting a read access violation. I think that the IMFMediaBuffer is being freed and then the data is not available anymore. How to make IMFMediaBuffer persistent? Also, how to create the shared_ptr out of the dangling data pointer?

**EDIT**

In the end I did the following

```
CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> pBuffer;
pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer);
DWORD length;
pBuffer->GetCurrentLength(&length);
unsigned char* data;
hr = pBuffer->Lock(&data, NULL, &length);
if (FAILED(hr))
    std::cout << "Failed to get pointer from buffer";
std::shared_ptr<unsigned char[]> datacopy(new unsigned char[length]);
unsigned char* datacopypointer = datacopy.get();
memcpy(datacopypointer, data, length);
```

**EDIT**

Here's a minimal reproducible example in one file.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <dshow.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <dvdmedia.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat")
#pragma comment(lib, "mf")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite")
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid")
#pragma comment(lib, "strmbase")

class SpinLock
{
private:
    volatile LONG dest = 0;
    LONG exchange = 100;
    LONG compare = 0;
public:
    void Acquire() {
        while (true)
        {
            if (InterlockedCompareExchange(&dest, exchange, compare) == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    void Release() {
        dest = 0;
    }
};

std::vector<CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer>> images;
HWND hwnd;
int ScreenWidth;
int ScreenHeight;
std::shared_ptr<SpinLock> videolock (new SpinLock());

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {

    }
    break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
}

template< typename T >
struct Deleter
{
    void operator ()(T* p)
    {
        DeleteObject(p);
    }
};

void StartRenderingInBackground() {
    while (true) {
        videolock->Acquire();
        if (images.size() > 0) {
            BITMAPINFOHEADER header = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 640, 480, 1, 24, BI_RGB, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
            BITMAPINFO info = { header, NULL };
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            HDC drawingHDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            unsigned char* data;
            DWORD length;
            images.at(0)->Lock(&data, NULL, &length);
            std::unique_ptr<HBITMAP__, Deleter<HBITMAP__>> hBitmap(CreateDIBitmap(hdc, &header, CBM_INIT, data, &info, DIB_RGB_COLORS));
            std::unique_ptr<HBITMAP__, Deleter<HBITMAP__>> scaledHBitmap(CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
            SelectObject(drawingHDC, hBitmap.get());
            SelectObject(hdc, scaledHBitmap.get());
            StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, drawingHDC, 0, 0, 640, 480, SRCCOPY);
            images.erase(images.begin());
        }
        videolock->Release();
    }
}

void StartCameraInBackground() {
    HRESULT hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

    IMFSourceReader* pReader = NULL;
    IMFMediaSource* pSource = NULL;
    IMFAttributes* pConfig = NULL;
    IMFActivate** ppDevices = NULL;

    hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pConfig, 1);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        std::cout << "Failed to create attribute store";

    hr = pConfig->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE, MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        std::cout << "Failed to request capture devices";

    UINT32 count = 0;
    hr = MFEnumDeviceSources(pConfig, &ppDevices, &count);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        std::cout << "Failed to enumerate capture devices";

    hr = ppDevices[0]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSource));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        std::cout << "Failed to connect camera to source";

    hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(pSource, pConfig, &pReader);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        std::cout << "Failed to create source reader";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        ppDevices[i]->Release();
    CoTaskMemFree(ppDevices);
    pSource->Release();
    pConfig->Release();

    DWORD streamIndex, flags;
    LONGLONG llTimeStamp;

    std::thread th(StartRenderingInBackground);
    th.detach();

    while (true) {
        CComPtr<IMFSample> pSample;

        hr = pReader->ReadSample(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, &streamIndex, &flags, &llTimeStamp, &pSample);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            std::cout << "Failed to get image from camera";

        if (pSample != NULL) {
            CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> pBuffer;
            pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer);
            DWORD length;
            pBuffer->GetCurrentLength(&length);
            unsigned char* data;
            hr = pBuffer->Lock(&data, NULL, &length);
            if (FAILED(hr))
                std::cout << "Failed to get pointer from buffer";
            videolock->Acquire();
            images.insert(images.begin(), std::move(pBuffer));
            videolock->Release();
        }
    }
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    AllocConsole();
    freopen_s((FILE**)stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Window";
    RegisterClass(&wc);
    hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, L"Window", L"Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
    HMONITOR currentMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, NULL);
    MONITORINFO monitorInfo;
    monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
    GetMonitorInfo(currentMonitor, &monitorInfo);
    ScreenWidth = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.right;
    ScreenHeight = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.bottom;
    std::thread th(StartCameraInBackground);
    th.detach();
    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm passing the images as IMFMediaBuffer to the other thread in a vector of IMFMediaBuffer protected by a SpinLock implementation. Is this a good way to pass data to another thread?

Also, it works at first but then the image freezes after some time. What do you think causes this problem?

Also, memory usage increases linearly of ~1MB every 15 seconds and then stops increasing when the image freezes.

Comment: I thought of never releasing the IMFMediaBuffer and releasing the unsigned char* instead. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Basically, I need the data in the unsigned char* format and I need to keep the data alive in multiple threads.

Comment: Maybe I need to copy the whole data in a new unsigned char* array and Release() the IMFMediaBuffer immediatly. That would be very ineficient though.

Comment: @Hans Passant You misunderstand the problem. The IMFMediaBuffer cannot remain because I need to send the data over on the network. I need the data in the unsigned char* format. I cannot call Release() later.

Comment: It's completely opaque, which problem you are trying to solve. It's very likely that your proposed solution isn't going to be a good fit.

Comment: The solution works. It just isn't efficient. I receive images from the webcam which is the pSample. Then I need to send data over the network. If I keep the data in the IMFMediaBuffer format, I can't send it using OpenSSL. OpenSSL expects the unsigned char format. I need it to be in the unsigned char* format and then delete the data later. Also, I need the data to keep alive in another thread.

Comment: Since the IMFMediaBuffer deletes the underlying data when released I need a copy of the data to keep it alive and still delete the IMFMediaBuffer immediatly after it is used. I think my solution is the best fit for my need.

Comment: `IMFMediaBuffer` is a container, not a format. `unsigned char*` is a type, used to describe the encoding. That's not a format, either. And OpenSSL doesn't care one bit about the format of the data you throw at it. It just expects a sequence of bytes, which [IMFMediaBuffer::Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfobjects/nf-mfobjects-imfmediabuffer-lock) returns. You seem to be confused at a *fundamental* level about what data is, and how it is represented to programming languages.

Comment: I'm not really confused. The IMFMediaBuffer::Lock method doesn't return a sequence of bytes. It returns a pointer to the sequence of bytes. That is the main problem. If I free the IMFMediaBuffer object, the underlying data is being freed as well. So when I try to access the "sequence of bytes" it throws an access violation. That is where you misunderstand the problem.

Comment: Why do you `Release` the `IMFMediaBuffer` too early, then? I mean, just keep it around for as long as you need it. If you need to access the data from multiple threads, marshal the interface across, making sure to bump its reference count. Drop each interface when you no longer need it. The final interface will automatically release the resources it controls. It's almost like you want to forego COM's reference counting just so that you can implement your own reference counting. For now apparent reason.

Comment: That is a possibility. My problem is that if I receive data from the network as well, I would need to write 2 rendering APIs. One which renders after using the lock method of the IMFMediaBuffer and one which renders directly. That would mean more coding.

Comment: I think it is a bad design decision by the devs at microsoft. They just thought that people would want to pass around an IMFMediaBuffer object which is totally inconvenient. I think that the Release()/destructor method of the IMFMediaBuffer should not release the underlying data buffer.

Comment: Basically, I would have one image which would be passed around as an IMFMediaBuffer (the image which I capture locally), and one image which would be passed around as a pointer to an array of unsigned chars (the image which I receive from the network). That is inconvenient to me. (I'm writing a video chatting application).

Comment: The fundamentals of COM aren't entirely difficult to understand. `Release` doesn't release the underlying buffer. It decrements the reference count. Once it hits 0, the underlying buffer is released. Assuming your code is correct, when the reference count drops to 0 there cannot possibly be any other place that holds a reference to this interface. It's starting to sound like you are trying to work around an issue that just became an issue due to a fundamental misunderstanding of how the system works.

Comment: When I say Release() releases the underlying buffer I'm just taking a shortcut to say the same as what you said. I know that Release() decrements references and then call the destructor once it reaches 0. The problem is I can't pass around an IMFMediaBuffer object. It is too inconvenient. Especially, that CComPtr is similar to unique_ptr in that it needs to be std::moved around which is inconvenient as well.

Comment: What I would like is that the IMFMediaBuffer object gets deleted while keeping the underlying data accessible. I thought maybe someone has a way to do that. But it seems like nobody really understands the problem and it is okay.

Comment: [CComPtr::CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptrbase-class#copyto). It looks like things are very inconvenient to you, because you do not quite understand how to use your tools. Anyway, seeing that you are avoiding the solution, I'm afraid I have nothing useful to offer to you. Good luck.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your time. I'll keep with my solution since it really answers the problem.

Comment: Why are you using a loop to copy 3 bytes at a time from `data` to `datacopypointer`? Why not just use `std::memcpy()` or `std::copy()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

COM interfaces are reference counted.  `std::shared_ptr` is also reference counted.  So, you don't really need to use `std::shared_ptr` when you can use the `IMFMediaBuffer`'s own reference counting instead (`CComPtr` will manage that for you).

`ConvertToContiguousBuffer()` outputs an `IMFMediaBuffer` whose initial reference count is 1.  So, simply pass that buffer around to your threads as needed, incrementing its reference count for each thread via its `AddRef()` method (which `CComPtr` can handle for you).  When each thread is done, it can call the buffer's `Release()` method (again, `CComPtr` can handle that for you), decrementing the reference count.  As long as the reference count is above 0, the `data` pointer will remain alive, until you `Unlock()` it.

In fact, even `IMFMediaBuffer::Lock()` is also reference counted!  The documentation says you can call `Lock()` multiple times, and must call `Unlock()` an equal number of times.  So, you don't really need to `Lock()` the buffer in the same thread that calls `ConvertToContiguousBuffer()` and then pass the `data` pointer around.  You could just pass the `IMFMediaBuffer` itself to your threads and let them each `Lock()` and `Unlock()` it as needed.  As long as its reference count stays above 0, the underlying data should not be freed.

```cpp
CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> pBuffer;

if (FAILED(pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer))
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to get media buffer";
    return;
}

// pass pBuffer to each thread as needed...
```

```cpp
// in each thread:
{
    CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> pBuffer = ...; // received from above
    DWORD length;
    unsigned char* data;
    if (FAILED(pBuffer->Lock(&data, NULL, &length)))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get pointer from buffer";
        return;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<IMFMediaBuffer, void(*)(IMFMediaBuffer*)> unlocker(pBuffer, [](IMFMediaBuffer *buf){ buf->Unlock(); });

    // use data up to length as needed...
}
```

But, if you really don't want to rely on this behavior, and would prefer to use `std::shared_ptr` instead, then you can wrap the `CComPtr` and `data` pointer inside of a simple `struct` that you can then pass around, eg:

```cpp
struct MediaBufferAndData
{
    CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> MediaBuffer;
    unsigned char* Data = nullptr;
    DWORD Length = 0;
    bool CanUnlock = false;

    MediaBufferAndData() = default;

    ~MediaBufferAndData()
    {
        if (CanUnlock)
            MediaBuffer->Unlock();
    }
};

std::shared_ptr<MediaBufferAndData> pBuffer = std::make_shared<MediaBufferAndData>();

if (FAILED(pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&(pBuffer->MediaBuffer))))
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to get media buffer";
    return;
}

if (FAILED(pBuffer->MediaBuffer->Lock(&(pBuffer->Data), NULL, &(pBuffer->Length))))
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to get pointer from buffer";
    return;
}

pBuffer->CanUnlock = true;

// pass pBuffer to each thread as needed...
```

```cpp
// in each thread:
{
    std::shared_ptr<MediaBufferAndData> pBuffer = ...; // received from above
    // use pBuffer->Data up to pBuffer->Length as needed...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer and comment. I'll use memcpy to copy the data.

Comment: COM interfaces, like `IMFMediaBuffer` have the **exact** same semantics as a `shared_ptr`. It is a mystery why you decided against using the former and went with the latter. The latter has **no** benefits. It accomplishes **exactly** the same as the former at the expense of an additional memory allocation and a copy.

Comment: I said earlier that I need to render the images and, if I use an IMFMediaBuffer,  I'll need to write 2 rendering code. One which renders the IMFMediaBuffer after using the Lock() method and one which renders directly. Some images I render come from the network. I receive a pointer to unsigned chars from OpenSSL. I'll need to write 2 code. One which renders the local images that I pass around as an IMFMediaBuffer and one which renders the network images that I get as a pointer to unsigned chars.

Comment: @user123 no, you do not need to write 2 rendering codes. You need only 1 rendering code, and it should concern itself only with the raw data, it should not care where that data comes from. You have access to the data pointer from the `IMFMediaBuffer`, pass it to the rendering code. Same with the network code. 1 renderer, 2 sources of data. Nothing that has been told to you so far prevents you from doing that. If you are having trouble integrating suggestions into your code, then you may need to redesign your code. Update your question to show what you are actually having trouble with.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I edited the question with a minimal example. I pass the IMFMediaBuffer to the thread but get other problems.

Comment: @user123 I see a LOT of issues with this code. But in particular, you have no exception safety around the `videolock` (why not use a `std::conditional_variable` instead?), no `Unlock()` calls on any of the `images` buffers, and several GDI objects are leaked in `StartRenderingInBackground()` on each loop iteration. Also, you really should not be drawing on the `HWND` from outside of its `WM_PAINT` handler at all. You should save the most recent `HBITMAP` and have `WM_PAINT` draw it every time. Call `InvalidateRect()` whenever the `HBITMAP` changes to trigger a repaint.

Comment: @user123 For that matter, if your `images` has multiple buffers in it, you are drawing all of the buffers onto the `HWND` until the `images` is empty, but you are unlocking the `videolock` for each image. Why not just lock the `images` 1 time and draw all of the buffers in a `for` loop before then unlocking the `images`? On the other hand, if your goal is to draw only 1 buffer on the `HWND` at a time, then why do you even have a `vector` of buffers at all? Why not just save and draw only the most recent buffer by itself?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Yes, I use a vector because I plan on having several images drawn at different positions (some coming from network). I'm probably gonna loop on all images before unlocking like you said. Also I'm gonna store std::pairs in the vector with an int to tell me to whom belongs each image. As to the Unlock() calls what do they do exactly? As to GDI, I know it is quite messy because I got it working by trial and error. I have a hard time to understand how GDI works. Also, is WM_PAINT called in the background if I call InvalidateRect() because I don't want my window to become irresponsive.

Comment: @user123 you can't keep `IMFMediaBuffer` locked indefinitely, you have to unlock it when you are done accessing its data, or else the memory will never be freed. As for `WM_PAINT`, it is asynchronous, generated by the window's message queue whenever the window needs to be redrawn onscreen. `InvalidateRect()` signals the window to repaint at its earliest convenience, it is not immediate. `WM_PAINT` is generated when there are no other pending messages for the window.